# Cambiar color de una div al mover el scroll

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Lo que deseo es que al mover el scroll, cambie el color de un div.

cambie de blanco a transparente

```
<div style="position : fixed;width : 100%;margin-top:-20px; background-color: white;height: 80px; " data-collapse="all" data-animation="over-left" data-duration="400" class="navbar w-nav  color_barra" >
```

Answer (score 2):

En este caso debes detectar el movimiento del panel para realizar el cambio del color en el contenido, una opción es la que sugiere [@MaximilllianLaumesiter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2234742/maximillian-laumeister) en su [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32675632/250260) en SOen. Detecta un movimiento mayor a 200 px cambia el color del div a color transparente, cuando es menor a 200px cambia a color blanco.

En este ejemplo cambia de color blanco a negro, para cambiar a transparente simplemente define el color `transparent` en lugar de `black` :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    $("#left-panel").scroll(function () {
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_pos > 200) {
            $("#left-panel").css('background-color', 'transparent'); //*Transparente
        } else {
            $("#left-panel").css('background-color', 'white'); //*blanco
        }          
    });
});
```

```css
#left-panel {       
    background-color: gray;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;        
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow:auto;       
    height:2000px;      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left-panel">
    <div style="height:5000px;">Contenido div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: El OP, no ha pedido algo así, sino simplemente al hacer scroll

Comment: No entiendo el comentario, ¿no ha pedido hacer que, se mas especifico?, al mover el contenido, cambia de color.

Answer (score 2):

Espero te sirva el siguiente ejemplo:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Poscion Scroll</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="posicion"><h1>Posicion: <small id="posicion"></small></h1></div>
<div id="div1">
    <h1 id="h1-1">Div 1</h1>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <h1 id="h1-2">Div 2</h1>
</div>
<div id="div3">
    <h1 id="h1-3">Div 3</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**scroll.js** `jquery`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$('#posicion').text(scroll);
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#posicion').text(scroll);
    /*Cambia el color del div cuando es distinto a 0*/
    if(scroll!=0){
        $('#div1').css({
            background: '#fff'
        });
    }else{
        $('#div1').css({
            background: '#066DFA'
        });
    }
});
});
```

**estilo.css**

```
html,body{
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
div{
position: static;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
h1{
margin:0;
}
#div1{
background-color: #066DFA;
}
#div2{
background-color: #FBF806;
}
#div3{
background-color: #FE2704;
}
.posicion{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 5%;
background-color: #FB0606;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
}
```

Es una manera sencilla de hacer el cambio de color del div

Comment: El OP nunca pidió que sólo fuera cuando el scroll no estuviera en 0

Comment: El punto es que la pregunta tenga una idea para lo que lo quiera aplicar, ya sea que en cierta altura haga algo o simplemente puede quitar la comparación, y solamente escuchar el evento `.scroll()`. Ya esta en @Asher si la acepta o no, saludos.

Comment: Te lo digo por experiencia, cuando a mi me respondian algo y recién estaba empezando en javascript, no entendía porque hacian ciertas cosas, y aveces aquellas cosas eran anexa a la solución, el podría decir, ¿Porque el scroll en 0 ? Hará algo especial ? Piensalo desde alguien que recién empieza

Comment: Lo entiendo, pero también se que desde varias perspectivas se puede llegar a algo mucho mejor, muchas respuestas diferentes te ayudan a visualizar las cosas desde otro angulo, eso lo se por experiencia, lo importante es aportar algo a los demas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , () => {
var d = document.getElementById("m");
document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
d.setAttribute("style","background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1)");
});
});

for(var i = 0; i<50; i++) { // Es solo para rellenar el body y tener la barra para hacer scroll, NO TOMAR EN CUENTA.
 document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```

```css
#m {background-color: white; width: 200px; height: 200px;}
body {background-color: gray;}
```

```html
<div id=m></div>
```

Comment: El OP ha pedido que cambie de color de blanco a transparente al mover el scroll. No cambia a los colores comentados y si mueves el scroll, el contenido no cambia de color.

Comment: Si cambia el color al mover el scroll, además nunca pidió con una determinada cantidad de pixeles, y ya ha sido modificado el color a blanco.

Comment: Es un ejemplo, por ejemplo yo preguntaría para que crear un bucle para agregar br ? : for(var i = 0; i<50; i++) {  . Veo que ya cambiaste el color al menos

Comment: En el mismo código expliqué el motivo, deberías leer supongo.